# 400 - Bad Request in Curl

Tags: php, curl

It seems like im getting a problem when Im trying to send a request to a server in php. The http api request is something like this:

`http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?minorRev14&apiKey=p9ycn9cxb2zp3k3gfvbf5aym&cid=55505&locale=en_US&hotelId=122212&stateProvinceCode=%20NV%C2%A4cyCode=USD&arrivalDate=12/27/2012&departureDate=12/28/2012&room1=2,&room2=2,18,15&room3=3,16,16,15&room4=3,&includeDetails=true&includeRoomImages=true`

I have the following part of my code in php where I believe the error is occuring:

```
$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?minorRev14';
$url .= '&apiKey=p9ycn9cxb2zp3k3gfvbf5aym';
$url .= '&cid=55505';
$url .= '&locale=' . $locale . '&hotelId=' . $hotelid . '&stateProvinceCode=' . $state . '&currencyCode=USD';

$url .= '&arrivalDate=' . $datefr . '&departureDate=' . $dateto . '&' . $details . '&includeDetails=true&includeRoomImages=true';
$header = "Accept: application/json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$ee       = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($ee);

print_r($retValue);
```

This is what I get from the print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) statement:

```
Array (
    [url] => http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?minorRev14&apiKey=p9ycn9cxb2zp3k3gfvbf5aym&cid=55505&locale=en_US&hotelId=122212&stateProvinceCode= NV¤cyCode=USD&arrivalDate=12/27/2012&departureDate=12/28/2012&room1=2,&room2=2,18,15&room3=3,16,16,15&room4=3,&includeDetails=true&includeRoomImages=true
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 181
    [request_size] => 340
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.469
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.125
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.125
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 349
    [speed_download] => 744
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 349
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.469
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array ( )
    [redirect_url] =>
)
```

I'm not sure what the solution can be and I have been looking at this problem for awhile now hopefully someone can help me thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
```

This way it   tells it what type of agent (browser, spider, etc) is requesting the content.

So finally, I modified your code to

```
<?php 
$url ='http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?minorRev14&apiKey=p9ycn9cxb2zp3k3gfvbf5aym&cid=55505&locale=en_US&hotelId=122212&stateProvinceCode=%20NV%C2%A4cyCode=USD&arrivalDate=12/27/2012&departureDate=12/28/2012&room1=2,&room2=2,18,15&room3=3,16,16,15&room4=3,&includeDetails=true&includeRoomImages=true';

$header = array("Accept: application/json");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$ee       = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($ee);

print_r($retValue);
?>
```

and it is working fine for me. Can you also check?

Comment: @Leigh added explaination, in CURLOPT_USERAGENT ,'USERAGENT' is self explainatory

Comment: @Leigh it is because some servers will block spiders /crawlers or bots and allows only browsers

Comment: This is the kind of information you should be adding to your answers **in the first place**. Not just a single line of code on its own.

Comment: Thanks I am check it now

Comment: Sorry user7282 i got a same error..

Comment: @SomethingWrong can you check now?

Comment: This trick worked for me (a curled page that worked before and all of a sudden, it would throw a 404 error all the time). Adding $_SERVER['USER_AGENT'] (to use mine) didn't work though, so this one is a keeper.

Answer (score 1):

There is something weird in :

&stateProvinceCode=%20NV%C2%A4cyCode=USD

```
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Converting it to plain ascii](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), its  "NV¤cyCode"

From my pov it should be like

&stateProvinceCode=NV&cyCode=USD

Just as information, what kind of error did you get from server?

Comment: 400 - Bad Request from curl responce

Comment: just the title.. i'm definitely tired today ;) did you try to change with a stateProvinceCode more "academic"?

Comment: just now i can change the stateProvinceCode and Currency code... But its not worked please help me

Comment: check how "$state" var is populated, cause it seems to contain garbage data

Comment: @SomethingWrong show us the working url of api and not-working yours after the fix (with `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`) so we could compare it. 400 - is a bad request, which means something in your url or headers is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Friends.. I got it..... Thanks for your cooperation....